# Groovy Gradle Sonar-runner Unit Testing and Code Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

Hi I have set up a groovy project analyzing with sonar-runner, it works for complexity, lines of code etc but the code coverage shows "-" and unit testing is 0%. 
This is the sonar-runner properties file 
I am using Groovy plug in 0.6 
Sonar runner 2.3 
Sonar Qube 3.7
Jacoc

```
sonar.projectKey=Groovy
sonar.projectName= Groovy SonarQube Runner
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=grvy
sonar.binaries=target/classes
sonar.libraries=lib
sonar.junit.reportsPath=test/unit
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=test/coverage/jacoco.exec

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

When running a SonarQube analysis with the SonarQube Runner, you should be aware that tests are not executed: this is why you get no result.

This means that you must make sure that they have been executed prior to the analysis, and the the results have been exported.

Just for information, you can have a look at the sample projects here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/groovy

Comment: Yes I have used these samples and the project works fine besides the code coverage and unit tests are - and 0%, respectively. These sample projects that are in SonarSorce repo dont not produce unit test nor code coverage (based on the sonar-runner.properties file)I tried Jacoco in the beginning but I guess that works only for Java projects. I have seen other groovy/gradle examples but they add a pom to the project installed code-coverage pllugin etc.  I was wondering if there is a way to produce code coverage and unit test just with sonar runner and (Cobertura || Emma possibly) ?

Comment: Another question, in the same projects the "Issues" metric is reporting to be 0. In all my groovy projects appears to be the same case? I have added 133 CodeNarc rules and the "sonar way" and I still have 0 issues on all of my groovy projects.

Comment: I agree with Fabrice but as User said, the problem still exists. I have a Groovy project and I have valid Unit and Integration tests. I run them before hand. Unit tests in Gradle's build scope and IT tests in target Tomcat's JVM scope (by setting / passing jacocoagent.jar to Target JVM's scope). Once I stop Tomcat, it flushes IT code coverage data to jaococoIT.exec file successfully. Until Target JVM is stopped, you won't get a valid Jacoco IT exec file even if it shows a valid file size. After this, when I run sonarRunner Gradle task / sonar-runner with valid sonar.* properties, same issue.

Comment: @Fabrice This is exactly what I'm looking, if you can help. I run tests before running any jacoco and sonar analysis. Still, Unit test coverage and IT tests coverage info is absent or 0%

Comment: @ Fabrice - SonarSource Team  - link is broken.